# How can I make sure a float will always be rounded up with PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding, precision, ceil

I want to make sure a float in PHP is rounded up if *any* decimal is present, without worrying about mathematical rounding rules. This function would work as follows:

```
1.1 to 2
1.2 to 2
1.9 to 2
2.3 to 3
2.8 to 3
```

I know the `round()` function exists but I don't see any function for rounding up if any decimal is found. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the [`ceil`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function:

```
$number = ceil(1.1); //2
```

Comment: Sometimes `ceil` (or `floor`) is not the right answer for rounding. You can easily get a calculation result that will behave unexpectedly: `ceil((0.1 + 0.2) * 10)` produces `4`!

Answer (score 24):

I know this is an old topic, however it appears in Google.  I will extend Blake Plumb's answer regarding precision.

```
ceil(1024.321 * 100) / 100;
```

Multiplying by 100 and dividing by 100 only works with one-hundredths.  This isn't accurate on tenths, one-thousandths, one-hundred thousandths, etc.

```
function round_up($number, $precision = 2)
{
    $fig = pow(10, $precision);
    return (ceil($number * $fig) / $fig);
}
```

**Results:**

```
var_dump(round_up(1024.654321, 0)); // Output: float(1025)
var_dump(round_up(1024.654321, 1)); // Output: float(1024.7)
var_dump(round_up(1024.654321, 2)); // Output: float(1024.66)
var_dump(round_up(1024.654321, 3)); // Output: float(1024.655)
var_dump(round_up(1024.654321, 4)); // Output: float(1024.6544)
var_dump(round_up(1024.654321, 5)); // Output: float(1024.65433)
var_dump(round_up(1024.654321, 6)); // Output: float(1024.654321)
```

**Notes:**

Thanks for the contributions from Joseph McDermott and brandom for improving my original snippet.

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!!! Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

The official [Ceil](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function will do that for you.

Taken from the example:

```
<?php
echo ceil(4.3);    // 5
echo ceil(9.999);  // 10
echo ceil(-3.14);  // -3
?>
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this question has long since been answered, but it came up when I did a google search on the topic. If you want to round up with precision, then a good method would be to use the ceil function and times the number by how many decimal points you want to represent and then divide by that number.

```
ceil(1024.321*100)/100
```

would produce 1024.33

Comment: So simple yet so helpful. Quite surprising `round()` can't handle this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I like Ash's response, although I would have:

```
$fig = (int) str_pad('1', $precision + 1, '0');
```

Makes sense that if I provide precision '2', I would expect it rounded to 2 decimal places. Matter of choice though I suppose. Thanks for the answer Ash, works well.

Comment: You're right, I totally missed this. I'll update the answer.