# PHP round half up doesn't work

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php echo round(0.572,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);?>
```

I want to round two decimals to half up, I expect a value as 0.58...
but the above code print 0.57

How can I do  this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093608/how-can-i-round-a-float-always-up-with-php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you expect 0,58 you don't have to use a "half round" but the ceil function

```
$v = 0.575;
echo ceil($v * 100) / 100; // show 0,58
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking just that

Answer (score 1):

The value `0.572` can not be rounded up to `0.58`, because the third decimal, `2`, is less than half (or `5`). If you were doing `round(0.575, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)` you would get `0.58`. In this case `0.57` is the correct rounded value.

If you wish to **always** round up from the 3rd decimal, regardless of its value you could use `ciel()` instead, but it requires a little additional math. A simple function to demonstrate rounding up always would be...

```
function forceRoundUp($value, $decimals)
{
    $ord = pow(10, $decimals);
    return ceil($value * $ord) / $ord;
}

echo forceRoundUp(0.572, 2); // 0.58
echo forceRoundUp(0.57321, 4); // 0.5733
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function round_up($value, $places)
{
  $mult = pow(10, abs($places));
  return $places < 0 ?
  ceil($value / $mult) * $mult :
  ceil($value * $mult) / $mult;
}

echo round_up(0.572,2);
```

Hope this will work for you!!