# PHP round number to 6 decimal places

Tags: php, math, php-7

I need to return a result of (1 / n!) * (1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n!), n>=1.
This is a CodeWars challenge! The code below returns 1.146652 for n = 8, but the correct result is 1.1466510000000001 or 1.146651.

How can I truncate this number correctly?

```
function factorial($val){
  $factor = 1;
  for($i=1;$i<=$val;$i++){
    $factor *= $i;
  }
  return $factor;
}

function going($n) {
  $val = 1/factorial($n);
  $somatorio = 0;
  for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){
    $somatorio += factorial($i);
  }

  return round($val * $somatorio,6);
}
```

Comment: Your math may be wrong somewhere, because `$val * $somatorio` equals 1.1466517857143 on my system, which rounds up.

Comment: Can i simply cut the number at 6 decimal place?

Comment: Yes, try number_format: http://php.net/number_format

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093608/how-can-i-make-sure-a-float-will-always-be-rounded-up-with-php, replace `ceil` and `up` with `floor` and `down`.

Comment: round resulting in 1.146652 is correct, since the digit number 7 is higher than 5, thus it rounds the 1 up to a 2. if you absolutely want the code to ignore the digits coming after the 6th digit, then you can use `floor`.

Comment: The correct result is 1,146651786! because the 1.146652 is correct!