# Round number up to nearest thousand

Tags: php, rounding

I need round a number up to the nearest thousand. I tried `round($x, -3)`, but the output is not really what I want.

Examples of the desired output:

```
999 => 1,000
1,000.0001 => 2,000
1,001 => 2,000
1,100 => 2,000
1,600 => 2,000
100,010 => 101,000
```

Comment: I imagine you could do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22225765/1790644) but opposite.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by combining [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) with some multiplication and division, like this:

```
function roundUpToNearestThousand($n)
{
    return (int) (1000 * ceil($n / 1000));
}
```

More generically:

```
function roundUpToNearestMultiple($n, $increment = 1000)
{
    return (int) ($increment * ceil($n / $increment));
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/SX82Y).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if there is a specific function for what you're after but you could do something like:

```
(int) ceil($x / 1000) * 1000;
```

Hope this helps!